# Good notation for finite partial functions from $\omega$ to 2

Tags: computability-theory, gm.general-mathematics, notation

I'm working in computability theory and need to use partial functions with finite domain from $\omega$ to 2 as approximations in my current paper.  Normally this is simply done using $2^{< \omega}$ but I need partial functions whose domain isn't an initial segment.  Is there any vaguely standard notation for this?

Note that specifically, I need domains that include arbitrary finite initial segments of each column so if you want to suggest a notation that works for that but not all finite partial functions from $\omega$ to 2 that's fine as well but I don't need to enforce that constraint so I'm fine with a general notation for a finite partial function.

Comment: $\mathrm{Add}(\omega,1)$

Comment: @AsafKaragila What is Add abbreviating here?  and shouldn't that be a 2 since the range is {0,1} = 2?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @PeterGerdes The Add$(\omega,1)$ notation refers to "the" forcing notion that adds $1$ Cohen-generic subset of $\omega$. Unfortunately, $2^{<\omega}$ and the larger set that you want are equivalent as forcing notions, so the notation Add$(\omega,1)$ can be used for either of them.

Comment: Kunen uses $Fn(\omega,2,\omega)$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ahh, that's not that helpful then but thanks.

Comment: @MonroeEskew  Thanks for the tip.  I looked in Kunen and when it's specifically finite partial functions he has the even shorter notation $\text{Fn}(\omega, 2)$.  I mean that's nice but it seems like more akin to when someone defines good in a paper than notation that could be meaningfully recognized elsewhere.  I mean it almost invites confusion with the set of finite functions.

Still, this has been very helpful even if only to find out there isn't something widely accepted I should be using.